# Any free or affordable resources for network training?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, gpu

I have a really large network that I need to train but I don't have enough computational power. I tried using Colab but colab doesn't allow multiple parallel runtimes. I'd like to use the caiver approach for finetuning my learning rate and other hyperparameters but I can't afford to babysit as it'll take me years. Could you suggest any online resources like Colab, Kaggle and such?

Comment: That is a really good question. I have thought the same thing. I have not done an exhaustive search but I doubt there are a lot of options out there. My own solution is to cut the problem down to a reasonable size to run on my own hardware. I take the divide and conquer approach as much as I can. Sorry, I can't be more helpful.

Comment: What about https://datalore.io/ ? They give you up to 3 parallel computations. Not sure if there other community-level limitations impact you/make your problem worse.